# What are the benefits of Q_UNUSED over omitting an argument name?

Tags: c++, qt

What are the benefits of using `Q_UNUSED` macro over omitting an argument name in the function?

`Q_UNUSED` version:

```
void f(int x) {
    Q_UNUSED(x);
}
```

Omitting version:

```
void f(int) {
}
```

I thought there are guidelines which say to use it somewhy, but I did not found anything about it [there](https://wiki.qt.io/Coding_Conventions). Next thought was that someday the omitting did not exist in the standard but the compiler does not throw the error on omitting the variable name for any standard (98, 03, 11, 14, 17).
So why Qt uses this macro if it is useless and makes one more place to write a mistake?

Comment: Shows intention rather than a potential typo to anyone reading your code, including yourself in 6 months time.  Also answers the question "just what was that parameter", by leaving the name in the code.

Comment: @RichardCritten Inline comment would show the intention too: `void f(int /*x*/) {`.

Comment: Yes, just thinking that this is "opinion based" and therefore should be closed.

Comment: @RichardCritten I am asking exactly this: if there is no much difference then it is, but if there is a major difference, then it can't be opinion based.

Comment: Consider `void f(int x) { assert(x > 0); Q_UNUSED(x); }`, in which case `x` is used in debug mode but unused in release mode.

Comment: @cpplearner that is the case it is useful, yes, thanks.

Comment: @RichardCritten I disagree, the answer appears to be opinion based but the question is legitimate because it is asking if there actual benefits/differences so that we can answer there is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Q_UNUSED` can prevent the compiler from overreacting at more than one case of parameter not handled. Also, we can have an object instantiated with no single call from it:

```
MyClass myObject;
Q_UNUSED(myObject)
```

The most frequent case for me is QMutexLocker:

```
void qtFunc()
{
   // and no other line of code in that function accesses `lock`
   QMutexLocker lock(&m_mutex);
   // it just protects this scope with some object shared with other threads
   Q_UNUSED(lock) // shut up, compiler
}
```

*And* theoretically (maybe often) we can have a similar situation, not necessarily mutex locker when we initially write the code with the object on stack and then decided instead to pass the reference to it via the parameter before we figured out the final use of it. I personally don't like to revisit such insignificant "moments" in the code to fix some warning. So I use Q_UNUSED right and left when the code unfinished.

P.S. Of course the very fact of compiler emitting the "unused-variable" warning depends on compiler's options.

Comment: In this case, compiler would not (AFAIK) emit an warning. If there are side effects in the destructor, the object is used.

Comment: Try. My GCC does. :)

Comment: It ends with "unused-variable". I cannot always control the compiler options in our big project.